# How to skip the first X entries using ElementAPI

Tags: plugin-development, entries, plugin-elementapi, json

I'm looking how to use the `.offset(x)` parameters of craft.entries inside the ElementAPI.

I tried to add `'offset' =>` 1 before, after and inside the `criteria` array, but the x first entries are still added to the JSON.

How can I skip the first X entries of ElementAPI?

Comment: It seems that `offset` only works when `pagination` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released Element API 2.6.0 with added support for the `offset` criteria param, in combination with `paginate => true`.

(Thanks to @missmatsuko for posting a GitHub issue about it: https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/issues/99)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `offset` doesn't work when `pagination` is set to `true` (which is its default value).

**If you don't need pagination for your results**, you can add your `offset` in `criteria` and set `pagination` to `false`.

**If you do need pagination and the desired `offset` is the same as `elementsPerPage`**, you can get your results starting from page 2. You'll have to make sure you're actually getting page 2 because it will return page 1 if there aren't enough results for a second page.

**If you do need pagination and the desired `offset` is different from `elementsPerPage`**, you can try what I've done here.

```
'stories.json' => function() {
    // Get get IDs of the "offset" entries. Set `limit` to the offset amount you want.
    $excludedIds = Entry::find()
        ->section('stories')
        ->limit(4)
        ->ids();

    // Form value for id in criteria to exclude the above entries.
    $criteriaId = count($excludedIds) ? ('and, not ' . implode(', not ', $excludedIds)) : null;

    return [
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => 'stories',
            'id' => $criteriaId,
        ],
        'pretty' => true,
        'elementsPerPage' => 6,
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
            return [
                'title' => $entry->title,
                'url' => $entry->url,
                'id' => $entry->id,
            ];
        },
    ];
},
```

I found that you can still paginate results with a value for `id` set in `criteria`. So, I've excluded the IDs of the offset entries and paginated the results with those entries removed.

I've also made an issue on the Element API Github repo to see if there's a better solution:
https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/issues/99

Comment: This answer might be for Craft 3.  For Craft 2 use the following element query:

$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'news';
$criteria->limit = 1;
$excludedIds = $criteria->ids();